# How to Get Image URL after uploading an image form android to Firebase?

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making an App that user uploaded images on Firebase storage. After Uploading the image i want to upload the Images's URL and other details to my own API. How can i get the Uri of that image which the user just uploaded.
[This](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/02/android-upload-image-firebase-storage-tutorial.html) tutorial teaches how to do the uploading but doesn't show how to get the image URL. I tried all the tutorials but none shows the thing that i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), you can call `.getDownloadUrl` in the `.onSuccessListener` to get the image URL.

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
// Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jen. Will firebase storage be good for uploading images for a app which will have 20-50 image uploads and 1000-5000 image fetches using that Url everyday in terms of performance and viability?

Comment: Firebase is a viable solution for that scenario. Do keep in mind that such volume could exceed the free tier. Find out more about pricing here: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

And if my answer is helpful, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Also Jen, if i have a google premium account, then can i use the firebase services for free as the volume increases?

Comment: Good question! I don't know much about pricing to be honest. Check out the FAQ here: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing or check with the account services support here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/

Answer (score 1):

You will get the download URL on the onSuccess callback. Check the following code

```
public static void storeInFirebase(Context context, Uri uri, String type) {

StorageReference riversRef = null;
                    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                  //to create a separate folder with all the pictures uploaded
      riversRef = mStorageRef.child("pictures/" + "unique_value");

                    UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(uri);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                DialogUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Log.d("downloadUrl", "" + downloadUrl);

            }
        });
                }
```