# I am trying to get download url from firebase but it gives me some another link like "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@b9761c8"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to get download url from `firebase` but it gives me some another link like "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@b9761c8"

[image]

Comment: You need to share your code as **TEXT** not as **IMAGE**

Comment: Check this [How to Get Image URL after uploading an image form android to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686647/how-to-get-image-url-after-uploading-an-image-form-android-to-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add listeners when retrieving the url.

> Please read the [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

```
taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the uri
        ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload(editText5.getText().toString(), uri.toString());
        // Wrap with Uri.parse() when retrieving

        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(imageUpload);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Edit part ?.....

Comment: @EkdanaiNantaharn I updated the answer, you should know where to replace.

Comment: Try the test.....

Comment: Can't you try it yourself?

Comment: I can do it, thank you very much

Comment: Hi jake  / HOW TO Retrieve Image from URL using Firebase Realtime Database in Android How to do ?

Comment: just use the url with an image loading library

Comment: HOW TO Retrieve Image from URL using Firebase Realtime Database code

Comment: @EkdanaiNantaharn Since you are asking a different question, you should ask/create a different question