# Store Url in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am relatively new to android development and I was attempting to save an image url from firebase storage to firebase realtime database.

However, when I save the link to the realtime database it is saved as a link like `"com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c834bfd"`

rather than a normal http link, it is saved like above and I am not sure exactly what I need to change.

```
    package com.example.android.gymbuddies;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class setUpDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username, fullName, height, weight;
    TextView dob;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    CircleImageView profileIV;
    Button saveBT;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    RadioGroup gender;
    RadioButton genderOption;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    private StorageReference profileImageRef;

    String currentUserID, strGender;
    final static int galleryPic = 1;
    private String TAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_up_details);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        gender = findViewById(R.id.gender);
        dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        saveBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBT);
        profileIV = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


        saveBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveAccountDetails();
            }
        });

        profileIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, galleryPic);
            }
        });

        dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        setUpDetailsActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });



        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: dd/mm/yyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                dob.setText(date);
            }
        };
        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileImage")){
                        String image1 = dataSnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue(String.class);
                        Picasso.get().load(image1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profilepic).into(profileIV);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Please enter you image first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==galleryPic && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!= null) {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);

        }

            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                    StorageReference filePath = profileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                    filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Profile image stored in firebase storage successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString().trim();
                                userRef.child("profileImage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(setUpDetailsActivity.this, setUpDetailsActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(selfIntent);
                                            Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Profile image stored in firebase database successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                        } else {
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Error Occured: not stored in firebase storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Error Occured: Image can not be cropped try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }

    }

    private void saveAccountDetails() {
        String musername = username.getText().toString();
        String mfullname = fullName.getText().toString();
        String mheight = height.getText().toString();
        String mweight = weight.getText().toString();
        String mdob = dob.getText().toString();
        gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                genderOption = gender.findViewById(checkedId);

                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.male:
                        strGender = genderOption.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.female:
                        strGender = genderOption.getText().toString();
                        break;

                    default:

                }
            }
        });



        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(musername)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mfullname)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter your Full Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mheight)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter your Height in cm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mweight)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter your Weight in lbs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mdob)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter your Date-Of-Birth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strGender)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select your Gender", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username", musername);
            userMap.put("fullName", mfullname);
            userMap.put("liftingGoal", "Default");
            userMap.put("height", mheight + " cm");
            userMap.put("weight", mweight + " pounds");
            userMap.put("dob", mdob);
            userMap.put("gender", strGender);

            userRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        sendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "Account created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(setUpDetailsActivity.this, "An Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private void sendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(setUpDetailsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please consider shorting your example to the parts of code that are relevant for your problem (e.g.) where you write to the db.

Comment: So you say that the value of `downloadUrl` before adding to the database is `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c834bfd`, right?

Comment: which version are you using for firebase-messaging ?

Comment: Calling `getDownloadURL` returns a `Task`. You need to wait for the task to complete, to get the download URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287588/i-am-trying-to-get-download-url-from-firebase-but-it-gives-me-some-another-link

Answer (score 0):

[image]this is all working,
First will try and understand how to firebase working. It's very easy enjoy.

## MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword,f_name,l_name,phone;
    private Button  btnSignUp,back;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    FirebaseStorage storage;

    private DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase,mCustomerDatabase1;

    ImageView profileImage;
    Uri resultUri  = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.chetan.printerprinting/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    ProgressDialog progress;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child("UploadFile");

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();



            btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            f_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f_name);
            l_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.l_name);
            phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
            back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
            profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_profile);





            profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        selectPdf();
                    }
                    else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},9);
                    }
                }
            });

            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String F_name = f_name.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String L_name = l_name.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String Phone = phone.getText().toString().trim();



                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(F_name)) {
                        f_name.setError("Enter First Name!");
                        return;
                    }


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(L_name)) {
                        l_name.setError("Enter Last Name!");
                        return;
                    }


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Phone)) {
                        phone.setError("Enter Phone Number!");
                        return;
                    }
                    if(isValidPhone(Phone)){

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone number is valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        phone.setError("Phone number is not valid");
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone number is not valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                        inputEmail.setError("Enter Email Address!");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (isValidEmail(email)){

                    }
                    else {
                        inputEmail.setError("Enter Valid Email Address!");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                        inputPassword.setError("Enter Password!");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                        inputPassword.setError("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!");
                        return;
                    }



                                        Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                                        userInfo.put("email", email);
                                        userInfo.put("password", password);
                                        userInfo.put("f_name", F_name);
                                        userInfo.put("l_name", L_name);
                                        userInfo.put("phone", Phone);

                                        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);
                                        final String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";

                                        if(resultUri != null) {
                                            StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
                                            storageReference.child("profileImageUrl").child(fileName).putFile(resultUri)
                                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                                            String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                                            mCustomerDatabase.child("profileImageUrl").setValue(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){ }
                                                                    else{

                                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                }
                                            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }else{


                                        }

                                    }



            });

            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });

        }



    public boolean isValidPhone(CharSequence phone) {
        boolean check=false;
        if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone))
        {
            if(phone.length() < 10 || phone.length() > 11)
            {
                check = false;
            }
            else
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            check=false;
        }
        return check;
    }


    public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 9 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            selectPdf();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please provide the permission", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    private void selectPdf() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,86);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 86 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri = imageUri;
            profileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select file", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }






}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FBFBFB"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#4B74FF"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Create an account"/>



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/text"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/f_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/image_profile"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/f_name"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/l_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/f_name"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/l_name"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Phone No."
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/l_name"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/phone"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="email"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/phone"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/email"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="password"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/email"
                android:maxLength="11"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/password"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/password"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

hope use full