# Unable to obtain user profile image from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

I'm currently working on a settings page for my app and have been trying to obtain the user profile image from the firebase storage. I am able to upload the picture from the storage.

However, the app does not produce the image onto the activity itself. Is there something wrong with my code?

[image: Original placeholder image disappears when I try to obtain image from firebase storage.]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_chat_toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/pikachu"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setting_username"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/set_profile_status"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/setting_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_status"
        android:hint="Hey, I'm available now!"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setting_updatebtn"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/set_profile_status"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rect"
        android:text="Update Settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. Java

   ```
   package com.shiminu1521462c.fyp_2;





   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

   import android.text.TextUtils;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
   import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
   import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
   import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
   import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
   import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
   import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
   import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
   import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.HashMap;

   import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

   public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private EditText etUsername, etUserStatus;
   private Button changeSettings;
   private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
   private Toolbar mToolbar;
   private String currentUserID;

   private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   private DatabaseReference RootRef;

   private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
   private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
   private ProgressDialog LoadingBar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

       mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_chat_toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");

       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
       RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
       UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

       InitializeFields();

       etUsername.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       changeSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               UpdateSettings();
           }
       });

       RetrieveUserInfo();

       userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
               galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
               galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
               startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);
           }
       });
   }

   private void InitializeFields() {

       changeSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setting_updatebtn);
       etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setting_username);
       etUserStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
       userProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
       LoadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
           Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

           CropImage.activity()
                   .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                   .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                   .start(this);
       }
       if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
           CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

               LoadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
               LoadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while your profile image is uploading...");
               LoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
               LoadingBar.show();

               final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
               StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

               filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Profile Image Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                           RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                   .setValue(downloadUrl)
                                   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                                           if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                               Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Image saved in Database successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                           }else{

                                               String message = task.getException().toString();
                                               Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
                       } else {
                           String message = task.getException().toString();
                           Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           LoadingBar.dismiss();
                       }
                   }
               });

           }
       }
   }

   private void UpdateSettings() {
       String setUsername = etUsername.getText().toString();
       String setStatus = etUserStatus.getText().toString();

       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUsername)) {

           Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your username..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)){

           Toast.makeText(this, "Please set a status..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
       else {

           HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
           profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
           profileMap.put("name", setUsername);
           profileMap.put("status", setStatus);

           RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).updateChildren(profileMap)
                   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                               sendUserToDashboardActivity();
                               Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Profile updated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           } else {

                               String message = task.getException().toString();
                               Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });
       }
   }

   private void RetrieveUserInfo() {
       RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
               .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                       if ((dataSnapshot.exists())
                               && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")
                               && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")))) {

                           String retrieveUsername = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                           String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                           String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                           etUsername.setText(retrieveUsername);
                           etUserStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                           Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);


                       } else if ((dataSnapshot.exists())
                               && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))) {

                           String retrieveUsername = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                           String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                           etUsername.setText(retrieveUsername);
                           etUserStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);

                       } else {
                           etUsername.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Please set and update profile information..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });
   }


   private void sendUserToDashboardActivity() {
       Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
       mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
       startActivity(mainIntent);
       finish();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
       return true;
   }

   }
   ```

Thank you.

Comment: We need more info, what app is? What language? Some code?

Comment: Sorry! I entered the question before uploading the code. Trying to edit it now!

Comment: Uploaded the code!

Comment: You have perfectly store image in Firestore. This code is not to fetch any value. This code only stores the value in the database.

Comment: you need to how to store the image in the database. follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760621/store-url-in-firebase/52761368#52761368

Comment: Yes, I am able to store the image, but how do I retrieve it for the profile image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my issue! This is the altered code, hopefully it helps others who need it! :)

```
 final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Profile image stored to firebase database successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                                } else {
                                                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error Occurred..." + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not load the image using the resultUri?

```
Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
Glide.with(this).load(new File(resultUri.getPath())).into(imageView);
```

Do that after image upload is successful.

Comment: does that mean that I have to use glide instead of picasso?

Comment: You can still use Picasso

Comment: I already have resultUri in my code just above the StorageReference filepath section. May I know where do I put the code that you've stated?

Comment: You can put that after image is saved in database. Inside if task.isSuccessful()

Answer (score 0):

have you added the internet permission in the manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, I've added it